# How to avoid man-db

Tags: rubygems

Processing triggers for man-db ...

Whenever I install a gem, it seems to be processing man-db. I am assuming these are help files, how do I avoid installing them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are speaking of the `rdoc` and `ri` gem documentation.  You can do this on the individual gem by passing the `--no-ri` and `--no-rdoc` flags when installing a gem:

```
gem install some-gem --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Alternatively, you can do this globally by configuring a `.gemrc` [configuration file](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11) in your home folder. You should just need to add this line:

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```